# ReloadSimulatorAsync produces "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

In my Universal Windows App I test iap purchases. I've done this before in another app, and it worked. Have no idea why it doesn't work this time. 
Here's the code:

```
    StorageFolder proxyDataFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
    StorageFile proxyFile = await proxyDataFolder.GetFileAsync("WindowsStoreProxy.xml");
    CurApp.LicenseInformation.LicenseChanged += () => Log("License info changed");
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator.ReloadSimulatorAsync(proxyFile);
```

And ReloadSimulatorAsync produces "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception! Suppose it's something to do with xml parsing, but of course, file exists and has the right format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<CurrentApp>
  <ListingInformation>
    <App>
      <AppId>[my app id]</AppId>
      <LinkUri>https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/[my app store code]</LinkUri>
      <CurrentMarket>en-US</CurrentMarket>
      <AgeRating>7</AgeRating>
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>MyTestApp</Name>
        <Description>AppDescription</Description>
        <Price>0.0</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
      </MarketData>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="product2" LicenseDuration="0" ProductType="Durable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>Durable1</Name>
        <Price>0.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
    <Product ProductId="amnt1" LicenseDuration="0" ProductType="Consumable">
      <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
        <Name>Consumable1</Name>
        <Price>0.99</Price>
        <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
      </MarketData>
    </Product>
  </ListingInformation>
  <LicenseInformation>
    <App>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
    </App>
    <Product ProductId="product2">
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
    </Product>
  </LicenseInformation>
  <ConsumableInformation>
    <Product ProductId="amnt1" TransactionId="00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Status="Active"/>
  </ConsumableInformation>
</CurrentApp>
```

Why could this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue if I use the XML you provided, because **AppId** may be not correct, here you may need to give GUID. You can replace the **[my app id]** with **988b90e4-5d4d-4dea-99d0-e423e414ffbc** Microsoft provided and try it again.

More detailed information about XML you can refer to [in-app purchase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials-using-the-windows-applicationmodel-store-namespace).

I also find [Store sample(demonstrates trials and in-app purchase)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/win10-1507/Samples/Store) you can refer to.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
 <CurrentApp>
  <ListingInformation>
<App>
  <AppId>988b90e4-5d4d-4dea-99d0-e423e414ffbc</AppId>
  <LinkUri>http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/988b90e4-5d4d-4dea-99d0-e423e414ffbc</LinkUri>
  <CurrentMarket>en-us</CurrentMarket>
  <AgeRating>3</AgeRating>
  <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
    <Name>In-app purchases</Name>
    <Description>AppDescription</Description>
    <Price>5.99</Price>
    <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
  </MarketData>
</App>
<Product ProductId="product1">
  <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
    <Name>Product 1</Name>
    <Price>1.99</Price>
    <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
  </MarketData>
</Product>
<Product ProductId="product2">
  <MarketData xml:lang="en-us">
    <Name>Product 2</Name>
    <Price>2.99</Price>
    <CurrencySymbol>$</CurrencySymbol>
    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
  </MarketData>
</Product>
   </ListingInformation>
 <LicenseInformation>
<App>
  <IsActive>true</IsActive>
  <IsTrial>false</IsTrial>
</App>
<Product ProductId="product1">
  <IsActive>true</IsActive>
</Product>
<Product ProductId="product2">
  <IsActive>false</IsActive>
   </Product>
</LicenseInformation>
 </CurrentApp>
```

Comment: Thank you! But where can I find the guid? on details of app I can see only family name and market link with number-letter index, but it's not a guid.

Comment: ah, have just found - you can use any guid for testing. Will check it when I get to the computer

Comment: with random guid it finally worked. I think it uses a legacy code (windows phone 7+), when you had to use guid instead of family id, so guid is needed.